# Issue with a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to run a kruskal.test on several hundred columns of a dataset using a loop. There are 21 columns on metadata in the spreadsheet that don't need to be analyzed in this fashion, but contain the grouping information I need to make the statistical analysis.

```
tomato = read.csv("2017_2018_16s_table_6.csv")
Tomcom = tomato[,22:713]

members <- colnames(Tomcom)

for (i in members) {
  kruskal.test(i ~ BS2, data = tomato)
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = i ~ BS2, data = tomato) :
>   variable lengths differ (found for 'BS2')

However, if I substitute i for a given column name, the analysis works.

Comment: Build up your formula string like this: `formula(paste0(i, " ~ BS2"))`. Something along those lines.

Comment: `members <- colnames(tomato)[22:713]`

Comment: @cory Rather than going the detour via strings, you can do this directly via unevaluated R expressions, e.g. `formula(bquote(.(as.name(i)) ~ BS2))`. This is longer in terms of character count but conceptually much more direct because it doesn’t manipulate and subsequently parse strings.

Comment: Alright, it's a one microsecond improvement. You win this one.

`microbenchmark(formula(paste0("y", " ~ BS2")), formula(bquote(.(as.name("y")) ~ BS2)))`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work, but if you post a sample data set I can confirm.

```
for (i in 1:length(members)) {
  kruskal.test(get(members[i]) ~ BS2, data = tomato)
}
```

Like the comment below this does not save the results.  Using the following is one way to store all the results in a data frame:

```
myfunction = function(member){

    kruskal.test(get(members[i]) ~ BS2, data = tomato)

}

 colnames(Tomcom)%>%
    unlist()%>%
    purrr::map(myfunction)
```

Comment: Looping over indices instead of names doesn’t have any advantage. The only difference to OP’s code is then the `get`. Either way, this look runs over the columns but discards the results. Using `lapply` instead fixes that: `lapply(members, function (x) kruskal.test(get(x) ~ BS2, data = tomato))`

Comment: I think it's typically advised that new users try to avoid `get` and `assign` as it's usually an indication that there is a better way.